# Practicality of zero-knowledge proofs

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I have on more than one instance come across statements which suggest that zero-knowledge proofs are not practical. One example is: "Our theoretical constructions use zero-knowledge proofs, and therefore they do not suggest a practical way of implementing a pseudonym system." from the paper [Pseudonym Systems](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-46513-8_14).

What is the basis for this? Is it a caution which was common in the past which is now obsolete? I can think of recent systems, e.g. Z-cash, which uses zero-knowledge proofs in practice.

Comment: My fifty cents of the contribution could be: take a look at _The Complexity of Zero Knowledge_, by Salil Vadhan.

Comment: The paper you are referencing is 20 years old. There has been quite some progress in the meantime :)

Comment: @DrLecter, that's really true! In fact, I was unable to point where is a good start-point...